# Parsing expressions with suffixes using pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I want to parse the following (simplified) recursive expressions using PyParsing:

```
foo
(foo + bar)
foo'attribute
foo + bar'attribute
foo.field
(foo'attribute + foo.field)'attribute
```

I came up with the following parser which works for all of the above expressions:

```py
        identifier = Word(alphas)
        expr = (
            infixNotation(
                identifier,
                [
                    (Literal(".") + identifier, 1, opAssoc.LEFT),
                    (Literal("'") + identifier, 1, opAssoc.LEFT),
                    (Literal("+"), 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
                ],
            )
            + StringEnd()
        )
```

What fails, however, are expressions that involve `.field` and the `'attribute` suffix together. While `foo.field'attribute` is accepted, `foo'attribute.field` yields

```py
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected end of text (at char 13), (line:1, col:14)
```

When exchanging the tuples for *attribute* and *field* of the `infixNotation`, the second expression parses and the first doesn't. Seems like the order/precedence is relevant.

Any ideas how to parse arbitrary recursive appearances of different suffixes?

Comment: Interesting use of a unary operator to restrict the form of the second operand. I originally was going to suggest making these binary operators, but then you could have invalid expressions after the `.` or `'` delimiter. Very cool!

Comment: @PaulMcG Thanks! And special thanks for making pyparsing - this library has served me well in many projects in the past!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each tuple in the list defines its own level of precedence. When one operator has a higher precedence than another, the lower precedence operator can only be used as an operand of the higher precedence one by using parentheses (note that `(foo'attribute).field` parses fine).

For unary operators, you usually want a single level of precedence for all postfix operators (and another for all prefix operators if you had any). The way you do that in pyparsing is by using a tuple containing a single rule that can match both operators:

```
(oneOf(". '") + identifier, 1, opAssoc.LEFT),
```

Comment: A shortcut for `Literal("X") | Literal("Y") | Literal("Z")` is `oneOf("X Y Z")`.  I was going to suggest making these binary operators instead, but I think you want to restrict the second operand to just being identifiers, so the novel unary approach used by the OP will work.

Comment: @PaulMcG Thanks, I changed it.